# Catch ExpandableListView group click event in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, expandablelistview

I wish to get selected item for the *GroupHeaderTemplate* in ExpandableListView. But How to catch ExpandableListView group click event in Xamarin Forms , I am finding Solutions for Xamarin Android but none for the Forms . Moreover List item selection only works for child , How to get clicked event for Group Items. Any Link or Reference would be helpful.

My updated Xaml

```
  <ListView VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                x:Name="HotelsList"  SeparatorColor="Black"
                                BackgroundColor="Transparent" ItemSelected="HotelsList_ItemSelected"
                                IsGroupingEnabled="True" 
                                IsPullToRefreshEnabled="true"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding StaffLoansList}"
                                RefreshCommand="{Binding LoadHotelsCommand}" >

                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ViewCell>

                                    <Grid VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" Margin="10" >
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>

                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <Image  Grid.Column="0" Aspect="AspectFit"  HeightRequest="20" WidthRequest="30" 
                                                       HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Margin="5"
                                                       VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                                            <Image.Source>
                                                <FileImageSource File="{Binding ImageStatus}" />
                                            </Image.Source>
                                        </Image>
                                        <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding actionName}" FontSize="15" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
                                                       HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                                       VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
                                        <Label Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding actionDate}" FontSize="15"
                                                       HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                                                       VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
                                    </Grid>
                                </ViewCell>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ViewCell>
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Label
                                            FontSize="16"
                                            Text="{Binding Name}"
                                            TextColor="Gray" 
                                            VerticalOptions="Center">


                                        </Label>

                                        <Image x:Name="ImgA" Source="{Binding StateIcon}"  Margin="0,0,5,0" HeightRequest="20" WidthRequest="20" HorizontalOptions="End">

                                            <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                                <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.DummyCommand, Source={x:Reference HotelsList}}" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>

                                            </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                        </Image>
                                        <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                                            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.ShowDetailCommand, Source={x:Reference HotelsList}}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>

                                        </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                                    </Grid>
                                </ViewCell>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                    </ListView>
```

ViewModel
In Constructor:

```
 ShowDetailCommand = new Command<StaffLoanPageViewModel>(Showdetail);
```

ViewModel Class

```
 public ICommand ShowDetailCommand { get; set; }
 public void Showdetail(object obj)
    {
        NavigationService.NavigateTo(ViewModelLocator.StaffLoanDetailPopupPage, Staffloans);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's easy in your first child of `ViewCell` just add a `GestureRecognizor`

```
<ViewCell>
 <Grid>
 .
 . 
 .
 <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
<TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.DoSomethingCommand, Source={x:Reference HotelsList}}"
                   CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
 </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
 </Grid>
 </ViewCell>
```

Then in your command receive this tap event

```
DoSomethingCommand= new Command(DoSomething);
```

And your Commands receiver would look something like this:

```
 private void DoSomething(object obj)
    {

    }
```

And in this `obj` object you will get your clicked item's details of the type which is bonded to the `ListView`, Note this will be a single `object` and not a `collection`

### Update:

The command property would look something like this:

```
public ICommand DoSomethingCommand{ get; set; }
```

Comment: DoSomethingCommand= new Command(DoSomething); , This would be a relay command ?. Moreover , would this work on Main list ( parent ) or on child ?, I want one with parent

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot to mention that it will be an `ICommand` updating my answer take a look, Also yes this would the parents click event, not the child! Do not worry I read your question properly before answering.

Comment: It is not detecting click @G.hakim

Comment: Can you update the code you have done so far!? In your question and let me take a look!?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193140/discussion-between-nancy-kanwar-and-g-hakim).